# OneToOne field in a django modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a OneToOne field corresponding to a user (user_id), and in my avatar upload form I get a drop down list of all users to select one, but I want django to fill it with the current logged in user. Also, when submitting the form, for some users I get this message "Profile with this User already exists."

For the first problem I think that inline-formsets are the solution, but I don't know how to apply [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) to my form. I have no clue about the second problem. I am creating the Profile with a signal every time a new user is created, and I don't know how to just update it. I'm new to django.

Here is the code for my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

The form:

```
from django import forms
from profiles.models import Profile

class AvatarForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'avatar_img', )
```

And the view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from profiles.forms import AvatarForm

def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AvatarForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = AvatarForm()
    return render(request, 'profiles/avatar_form.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Thanks.

Update with the solution... I added this to the form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'true'
    self.fields['user'].widget = HiddenInput()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use initial argument for the form. When creating form object in your view you can give an initial argument for your form.

In your view.

This

```
form = AvatarForm()
```

can be replaced with

```
form = AvatarForm(initial={'user': request.user})
```

[This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) reference should be helpful to you.

Comment: That selects the current logged in user, but the field is still shown in the form, so any user could change it and update another user's avatar. If I remove the 'user' field in the form, I get a "Column 'user_id' cannot be null" error. That's why I thought it had to be done using the inline formset. Even with that field hidden, I don't think that's a solution as it could still be edited by a malicious user.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how to deal with the "Profile with this User already exists." message?

Comment: You have to ask a new question for this. Otherwise your original question will divert. I suggest accept this question's answer if it helped you and ask a new question we will be happy to help you there